# how to delete rows with less than 2 columns in a data file in linux?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, columns

If the input look like this:

```
    1
    2 4 5 6 7 19
    20
    22
    24 26 27 
    29 30 31 32 34 40 50 56 58
    234 235 270 500
    1234 1235 1236 1237
    2300
```

I want to delete the rows with less than 2 columns, so the output should look like:

```
    2 4 5 6 7 19
    24 26 27 
    29 30 31 32 34 40 50 56 58
    234 235 270 500
    1234 1235 1236 1237
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As steeldriver commented:

```
awk 'NF>1' input > output
```

Another way:

```
grep '[^ ] [^ ]' input > output
```

(look for a non-space character followed by a space, followed by a non-space character).

To edit it "in-place":

```
sed -i '/[^ ] [^ ]/!d' input
```